# Get the actual file size vs apparent size in GO

Tags: go, filesystems, sparse-file

"*fs.sys.Size*" (fs being *fileStat* in the *os* package) returns the apparent size of a file. This isn't ideal when dealing with sparse files.

Is there a way to get the actual file size in GO? Or all applications are bound to get the converted metadata that represent empty blocks as real ones?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looks like the [Stat_t structure](https://golang.org/pkg/syscall/#Stat_t) filled using stat/fstat calls from the  [Syscall package](https://golang.org/pkg/syscall/) is all you need. Just multiply Blocks by 512 to get the disk space consumed.

Comment: Indeed it does. Thanks.

Comment: Why 512 and why not Blksize?

Comment: @VarunV st_blksize is not the same as 512. See man page for stat(2), gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Attribute-Meanings.html etc.

Comment: Thanks. Clarified now @itisravi